# DocumentDB Interface Properties

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Is DocumentDb smart enough to correctly store and hydrate properties on a document that are interfaces?  MongoDb handles this beautifully by storing the type in a field inside the document on the server.

```
public class Customer
{
    public string Name{get;set;}

    // Does this work correctly when saving and retrieving?
    public IPolicy Policy{get;set;}
}

public interface IPolicy
{
    decimal Rate{get;set;}
}

public MagicPolicy : IPolicy
{
    public decimal Rate{get;set;}
}

public SuperPolicy : IPolicy
{
    public decimal Rate{get;set;}
    public string ImAnExtraProperty{get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes!  But not out of the box.  It uses Newtonsoft.Json to serialize.  So you can make the magic happen by adjusting the serializer settings:

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () =>
{
    return new JsonSerializerSettings()
    {
        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto
    };
};
```